# PHP divide string by new line(\n) character

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have string

```
$string = "one
two
three
four";
```

Q: How to divide string by `"\n"` character to array as :

```
array ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
```

Comment: `explode("\n", $string)` ?

Comment: sure you have next line on each string?

Comment: If it's in a linux environment try exploding on `\n`, if on windows then try `\r\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the explode function and use the *newline* character:

```
$array=explode("\n",$string);

print_r($array);
```

Having said that, different OS will use different new line breaks. Some will use `\n` while others will use `\r\n` which you might want to look into.

You can combine what you are doing with the [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function which covers all the options if you really want to - though I would consider it potentially overkill/complicating the issue:

```
$array=explode("<br>",nl2br($string,false));
print_r($array);
```

Comment: would `\r\n` be required to cover other types of new line encodings

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [PHP_EOL constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) which make sure to choose good delimiter :

```
$array=explode(PHP_EOL,$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exploding your string into array

```
$result = explode("\n", $string);
```

Comment: I think `'\n'` won't work, you need to use `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after the explode function?

```
$cake = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $cake);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $string = "one
        two
        three
        four";

    $arr=explode("\n",$string);
    foreach($arr as $row){
     echo $row.",";
    }
```